# Camera wide preview on portrait

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I've read allot on line for orientations of cameras, and preview but nothing match to my problem.

**My wish:** I want to take a landscape preview while my cellphone is in portrait mode.

I'm setting my camera preview size to `640x360` (16:9)
When my cell is in landscape my preview is showing correctly.

[image: Image taken in landscape]

When i'm turning my cell to portrait, my preview shown as bellow

[image: Image taken in portrait].

The rotation is not my problem.. I know that i need to rotate it myself. but then the resolution of the image will turned as well - `360x640` (My wish is `640x360`)

The question is, can i have a wide preview like when my cell is in landscape mode, and really is in portrait ? without changing the preview size to `360x640` and then rotate (btw, the camera does not support this preview size and it would crash).

For the sake of the question i'm using `camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer`

and saving the frame

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/temp/0.jpg");
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(frame, ImageFormat.NV21, 640, 360, null);
yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, 640, 360), 50, fOut);

fOut.flush();

fOut.close();
```

Comment: I think what you want is not possible, because the camera's physical sensor is oriented to be longer in the phone's longer axis. The best you can do is take a higher resolution preview in portrait orientation and crop the top and bottom of it to appear landscape, but this will narrow the FoV.

Comment: Yeah, This is what i thought so. Just thought i'm missing something.. My app also supports HD resolutions, and for that i can't use the idea of higher resolution and cropping.. Thanks for the fast response.